# How to create an alias for linux server name?

Tags: linux, hostname, opensuse

The openSUSE server name is 'darkhelmet'. I want to create an alias 'dh' for it. So I can also type 'ssh dh' and 'http://dh' would work too.

What file/files and where do I have to edit to make this happen?

Extract from /etc/hosts from darkhelmet

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts
127.0.0.2       darkhelmet.edumate darkhelmet
10.0.0.22       db2workgroup db2workgroup
```

[root][skroob] **nslookup darkhelmet**

```
Server:     10.0.0.10
Address:    10.0.0.10#53

Name:   darkhelmet.edumate
Address: 10.0.0.22
```

Comment: What is your local DNS setup?

Comment: I have no idea. How can I find out?

Comment: Your nslookup output shows it as 10.0.0.10 - see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `nslookup` would indicate that `10.0.0.10` provides a DNS server. Do you have access to it? If not, then unfortunately you're out of luck.

Since you don't have access to the server, you'll need to ask the admin to add this entry to the zone file (or one to this effect):

```
dh.edumate.    IN CNAME darkhelmet.edumate.
```

Assuming that you (all) have `search edumate` in your `/etc/resolve.conf`.

---

*I'm going to leave this previous answer for reference, otherwise this entire process won't make too much sense to others:*

I am assuming you have at least 2 machines.

1. `darkhelmet`
2. All the other other ones that need to connect to `darkhelmet`

In this case, you need to edit `/etc/hosts` on the machines that you want to connect to `darkhelmet` on (but you can also do this on `darkhelmet` if you want it to be able to connect back to itself as `dh`).

e.g.

```
 1.1.1.1    dh
```

where `1.1.1.1` represents the IP that `darkhelmet` has. That way `ssh dh` and `http://dh/` will work as expected.

Comment: Would this change be picked up automatically or do I have to do/restart something?

Comment: It would depend on the tool, most of the time it's picked up automatically and instantly. Try `ping dh` at a terminal and see if it resolves to the IP or not.

Comment: I added `dh` to this like `127.0.0.2       darkhelmet.edumate darkhelmet`. `ping dh` from dh works but not from other server on the network. `ping darkhelmet` from the same server works.

Comment: oh. I got it now. Is there any way I can do that at one place? Like name server or something like that?

Comment: For that, you'll need to tell us more about your setup. If you can tell us how all the other servers can already resolve `darkhelmet` to an IP, it should be the same method to alias it to `dh`

Comment: How can I find out? On the `skroob` server where I can do `ping darkhelemt` but `ping dh` doesn't work /etc/host doesn't contain any darkhelmet string.

Comment: Update your question with the output of `nslookup darkhelmet` please

Comment: OK. I don't have access to 10.0.0.10 and won't have access. I can ask admin to do the change for me. Could you explain what needs to be done? So I can exactly tell him what to do?

Comment: Have a look at the update